# Ajaxify Plugin Issue: jQuery Validation Initialization and Navigation Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm encountering two issues with the integration of the ajaxify plugin (https://4nf.org/ajaxify.js) and jQuery validation (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js) in my multi-page web application.

Issue 1: jQuery Validation Initialization

I have multiple pages, and I'm using the ajaxify plugin to navigate between them. When I include/import jQuery validation in a specific page, for example, page2.php, using the CDN, the validation doesn't seem to initialize properly during the ajaxification of the page. However, if I include it in the head element, it works. The challenge is that I have different pages, and some of them do not require form validation. Importing it in the head element increases unnecessary page load. How can I ensure proper initialization of jQuery validation when included within specific pages during ajaxification?

//Example code for dashboard.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>dashboard</title>
    <script src="https://4nf.org/ajaxify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a href="dashboard.php" class="jqlink">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="page1.php" class="jqlink">Page1</a>
    <a href="page2.php" class="jqlink">Page2</a>
</div>
<main class="container">
    <div>DASHBOARD</div>
</main>
<footer>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            let ajaxify = new Ajaxify({
                selector : '.jqlink',
            });
        });
    </script>
</footer>
```

//Example code for page1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>page 2</title>
    <script src="https://4nf.org/ajaxify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a href="dashboard.php" class="jqlink">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="page1.php" class="jqlink">Page1</a>
    <a href="page2.php" class="jqlink">Page2</a>
</div>
<main class="container">
    <form method="post" id="createForm">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <button type="submit">save</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#createForm').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                rules: {username: { required: true },},
                messages: {username: { required: "Enter a username" },}
            });

            $(document).on('submit', '#createForm', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);

                if ($(form).valid()){
                    alert(1)
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</main>
<footer>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            let ajaxify = new Ajaxify({
                selector : '.jqlink',
            });
        });
    </script>
</footer>
```

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve these challenges. Thanks in advance!